# router navigation not working after login success

Tags: angular6, angular5, angular7

angular router not working after login success.
I have Auth Module
Under Auth module i have login components

I have Admin Module
Under Admin module i have 3 components
1).admin component 
2).admin-dashboard
3).blog component

In admin.component.html 
written (router-outlet) tag.

//getting login success and userdata

{"result":"success","UserId":"U-001","UserName":"Super Admin","UserEmail":"admin@dw.com"}

if result is success trying redirecting to admin component. but it is not working.

please check the code.where i did the mistake?.

Thanks in advance.

app.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
//import { PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomPreloadingStrategyService } from './custom-preloading-strategy.service';
import { CustomPreloadingWithDealyStrategyService } from './custom-preloading-with-delay-strategy.service';

const routes: Routes = [
 {
 path:'',redirectTo:'/login',pathMatch:'full'
 },
 {
   path:'**',component:PageNotFoundComponent
 }
 ];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
   {
     preloadingStrategy:CustomPreloadingWithDealyStrategyService
   })],
   providers: [CustomPreloadingStrategyService,CustomPreloadingWithDealyStrategyService],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { MatToolbarModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatInputModule  } from '@angular/material';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { AdminModule } from './admin/admin.module';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { httpInterceptorProviders } from './http-interceptors/index';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
   AppComponent, 
   PageNotFoundComponent, HeaderComponent ],

 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   DragDropModule,
   FormsModule,
   ReactiveFormsModule,
   AlertModule.forRoot(),
   BrowserAnimationsModule,
   HttpClientModule,
   MatToolbarModule, 
   MatFormFieldModule, 
   MatInputModule, 
   MatDatepickerModule, 
   MatNativeDateModule,
   AdminModule,
   AuthModule,
   AppRoutingModule],

   exports: [MatToolbarModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule,AdminModule,AuthModule],
 providers: [Title, AuthService,httpInterceptorProviders],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
 constructor ()
 {
   console.log('App Module load');
 }
}
```

admin.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { AdminDashboardComponent } from './admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.component';
import { BlogsComponent } from './blogs/blogs.component';
import { AuthGuard } from '../auth/auth.guard';


const routes: Routes = [
   {
   path: 'admin',
   component: AdminComponent,
   canActivate: [AuthGuard],
   children: [
     {
     path: '',
     children: [
       { path: 'blogs', component: BlogsComponent },
       { path: '', component: AdminDashboardComponent }
     ],
   }
 ]
 }
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
   providers: [],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

admin.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';
import { AdminRoutingModule } from './admin-routing.module';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { AdminDashboardComponent } from './admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.component';
import { BlogsComponent } from './blogs/blogs.component';


@NgModule({
 declarations: [AdminComponent, AdminDashboardComponent, BlogsComponent],
 imports: [
   CommonModule,ReactiveFormsModule,AdminRoutingModule
 ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Route, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { Loginuser } from './loginuser';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-login',
 templateUrl: './login.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
 submitted = false;
 LoginForm:FormGroup;
 SuccessAlert : string;
 WarningAlert : string;
 showSuccessAlert = false;
 showWarningAlert = false;
 isLoggedIn : boolean
 constructor(private router:Router,private fb: FormBuilder, private authservice: AuthService) 
 { 
   this.LoginForm = fb.group({
     emailid: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
     password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(8)])],
   })
 }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.authservice.logout();
 }

 LogInUser(){
   let login = this.LoginForm.value;
   this.checklogin(login);
 }
 checklogin(loginUser: Loginuser){
   this.authservice.userlogin(loginUser).subscribe(
     data =>{
        if(data["result"]=="success"){
          this.showSuccessAlert = true;
          this.SuccessAlert = data["result"];
          this.LoginForm.reset();
          localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(data));
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
          this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
        }  
        else
        {
          this.showWarningAlert = true;
          this.WarningAlert = data["result"];
        }
     }
   )
 }
}

auth.guard.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad, Route, UrlSegment, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

 constructor(private router: Router, private authservice: AuthService){}
 canActivate(
   next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
   state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree {
     if(this.authservice.isLoggedIn) {
       return true
     }
     else
     {
       return false
       this.router.navigate(['/login']);
     }      
 }
 canActivateChild(
   next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
   state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
   return this.canActivate(next, state);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the **router.navigate** that does not redirect.

Test the following codes to resolve your issue:

```
this.router.navigate(["../admin"]);
```

or

```
 this.router.navigateByUrl('/admin');
```

Comment: thank you @mojtaba. may i know why router.navigate is not working

Comment: @konda probably because you didn't add admin-routing.module to app.module with lazy load because I think this is what you wanted to do. Try this in your app.module.ts: , { path: '', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule', canLoad: [AuthGuard] }. You need to have canLoad in AuthGuard. Try something like this in your AuthGuard: canLoad(route: Route) { if (this.authService.isAuth()) { return true; } else { this.router.navigate(['/login']); } }. After you did all of this, your solution might work properly without the need of navigateByUrl. Lazy Load on routes need to have canLoad.

Answer (score 0):

this is worked for me.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

this.location.replaceState('/');
this.router.navigate(['home']);
```

> this.location.replaceState

for replace history instead of pushing so if the user goes back it won’t go back to the url that the user was on, but the one before.

Answer (score -1):

router.navigate will not work directly because queryParams is Observable, so you cannot get parameters from it in this way.

Try this

this.router.navigate['../admin']